# What Kind of scroll view to contain 2 tableviews and collectionview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have complex view that contains Image slider(collectionView),List of offers(tableView) and List of Services (TableView), The main Content View should be scrollable and all subviews should not be scrollable.

I tried to make the parent view UIScrollView  but i got a problem that when the first tableview items exceeds the screen limit its not showing the exceeded elements.

I tried also to force full tableview height but i had a problem with scrolling

```
self.tableView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.tableView.contentSize.width,
                                   height: self.tableView.contentSize.height)
```

Is there a way to force showing all the tableview elements ,or should i use another type than UIScrollView?

[Here is an image for what i want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5no5B.png)

Comment: U should add image for the UI u want to display here, i dont really know what you mean here. But maybe you should add 3 container view for each of your table view and collection view, then add them inside your scrollview. there you can control each view separate view controller.

Comment: I don't know if it would seem too complicated, but using the UIScrollView to lay all this out might be difficult in my opinion. I might go about it by making a tableview with a different cell for each segment of your design. This is because the outermost tableview will handle your vertical scrolling and the sizing for each segment. Then it would be easier to deal with each segment on cell by cell basis, especially since the collection views seem like they are horizontal and not vertical.

Comment: I would use a single table view with multiple custom cells for each element.

Comment: @MaiQuânNguyễn Sorry this is my first post here so i am not allowed to upload embed images but i can embed image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5no5B.png

Comment: @AlanS thank you for your help, I will go with your structure.

Comment: @Desdenova thanks, i will go with that.

Comment: @AhmedFahmy for each table view cell, u must calculate each one height correctly then sum all of them as table view height. Because only your scroll view can scroll, so i think u r already disable scroll for table view. So the content height of your table must be your table height. And like i said above, try container view for each section, it will be more easy than include all of them inside one view controller. You are new to this ? So just dont rush anything.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to disable your UITableview scroll like:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

then all you need to get count of tableview element multiply it by the height of your tableview cell and set that height to tableview like:

```
tableViewHeight.constant = count * z
```

Where z is height of tableview cell.
All set now.